# Append is bring a syntax error back when called more than once in a program

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, append

I am trying to program a simple function. It is a function that takes on different forms depending on the value of proton numbers provided.

The proton numbers are provided in the list called "Z_min."

What I need to do is to calculate the function and store the values in an array so I can plot the values later.

I am a bit rusty in Python, but the way I am trying to store the computed values is by using .append to add it to a list in my python program, but this keeps bringing back a syntax error whenever .append is called more than once inside the for loop. However, the way the loop is constructed, .append should only be called once in the body of the loop in a single iteration.

Can you please help me figure out why this happening?

```
import math as m
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a_V = 15.75
a_S = 17.8
a_C = 0.711
a_A = 23.695
a_P = 11.2

Z_min = []
A = []
BA = []

for A_idx in range(0,301):
    Z_min_val = (A_idx/2) * (1 +(a_C/(4*a_A))*A_idx**(2/3))**(-1)
    A.append(A_idx)
    Z_min.append(round(Z_min_val))


for i in Z_min:
    if (A[i]%2 == 0):
        if (Z_min[i]%2) == 0:
            #print("This is even: ", Z_min[i])
            if (A[i] == 0):
                BA_val = 0
                BA.append(BA_val)
            else:
                BA_val = (a_V*A[i] - a_S*(A[i])**(2/3) - a_C*(Z_min[i](Z_min[i]-1))/((A[i])**(1/3)) - a_A((A[i]-2*Z_min[i])**2)/(A[i]) + a_P*(A[i])**(-1/2))
                BA.append(BA_val)
        else:
            #print("This is odd: ", Z_min[i])
            BA_val = (a_V*A[i] - a_S*(A[i])**(2/3) - a_C*(Z_min[i](Z_min[i]-1))/((A[i])**(1/3)) - a_A((A[i]-2*Z_min[i])**2)/(A[i]) - a_P*(A[i])**(-1/2))
            BA.append(BA_val)
    else:
        B_by_A_val = (a_V*A[i] - a_S*(A[i])**(2/3) - a_C*(Z_min[i](Z_min[i]-1))/((A[i])**(1/3)) - a_A((A[i]-2*Z_min[i])**2)/(A[i]))
        B_by_A.append(B_by_A_val)
```

Comment: Post the full error message.

Comment: If you're getting a syntax error, please show us the error.  Don't just _tell_ us about it.

Comment: I don't get a syntax error when I try your script. I get an error `'int' object is not callable`

Comment: Because of things like this: `Z_min[i](Z_min[i]-1)`. `Z_min[i]` is an integer, why are you trying to call it as a function with `Z_min[i]-1` as the argument?

Comment: What line are you getting the error?

Comment: @Barmar Thank you very much! I was able to fix the error before being able to update the post with the error message. I will make sure that I post the entire error message next time I post something. Your suggestion about the Z_min[i] being an integer helped a lot and made me realize that I missed adding " * " in a few places.

Comment: @CalebGoodman Thank you very much! I was able to fix the error before being able to update the post with the error message. I will make sure that I post the entire error message next time I post something.

Comment: @JohnGordon Thank you very much! I was able to fix the error before being able to update the post with the error message. I will make sure that I post the entire error message next time I post something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that probably you might want to use `*` in a few places:

```
import math as m
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a_V = 15.75
a_S = 17.8
a_C = 0.711
a_A = 23.695
a_P = 11.2

Z_min = []
A = []
BA = []
B_by_A = []

for A_idx in range(0,301):
    Z_min_val = (A_idx/2) * (1 +(a_C/(4*a_A))*A_idx**(2/3))**(-1)
    A.append(A_idx)
    Z_min.append(round(Z_min_val))


for i in Z_min:
    if (A[i]%2 == 0):
        if (Z_min[i]%2) == 0:
            #print("This is even: ", Z_min[i])
            if (A[i] == 0):
                BA_val = 0
                BA.append(BA_val)
            else:
                BA_val = (a_V*A[i] - a_S*(A[i])**(2/3) - a_C*(Z_min[i]*(Z_min[i]-1))/((A[i])**(1/3)) - a_A*((A[i]-2*Z_min[i])**2)/(A[i]) + a_P*(A[i])**(-1/2))
                BA.append(BA_val)
        else:
            #print("This is odd: ", Z_min[i])
            BA_val = (a_V*A[i] - a_S*(A[i])**(2/3) - a_C*(Z_min[i]*(Z_min[i]-1))/((A[i])**(1/3)) - a_A*((A[i]-2*Z_min[i])**2)/(A[i]) - a_P*(A[i])**(-1/2))
            BA.append(BA_val)
    else:
        B_by_A_val = (a_V*A[i] - a_S*(A[i])**(2/3) - a_C*(Z_min[i]*(Z_min[i]-1))/((A[i])**(1/3)) - a_A*((A[i]-2*Z_min[i])**2)/(A[i]))
        B_by_A.append(B_by_A_val)
```